# OpenGL sampler object not updating bound texture

Tags: c, opengl, texture-mapping

I am currently binding a sampler object to a texture unit (GL_TEXTURE12 to be specific) with

`glBindSampler(12, sampler)`

and the initial settings are very visible compared to the textures own settings. But when I change the samplers parameters with

`glSamplerParameteri(sampler, GL_TEXTURE_***_FILTER, filter);`

the texture bound to the texture unit filters just the same as it did before with no apparent change from any perspective.

I have tried re-binding the sampler to the texture unit again after the parameter change but I'm pretty sure this isn't required.

What changes can I make to get this working?

Comment: You do not bind textures to samplers, they are always bound to texture image units. The only thing that sampler objects changed was that they separate sampler state from texture objects whenever a non-zero sampler object is bound to a texture image unit. To make this a little bit more clear, `GL_TEXTURE12` is the name of a **texture image unit**... a binding point for texture objects and sampler objects. I know this sounds like a lot of pedantic nonsense, but part of your problem may be a misunderstanding of terms.

Comment: I understand completely. You just told me a bunch of useless information I already knew :P thanks though, I edited the question to reflect the issue you pointed out.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more code? In particular, the code where you bind a texture object to texture unit 12. Even after updating the question, the statement: "I have tried re-binding the texture unit to the sampler again [...]" is worded confusingly.

Comment: If you find my wording confusing then I don't think you can help me; I think I mean to say that I bound the sampler to the texture, though.

Textures are bound to the unit throught-out a loop of all of my meshes like this:

    `gl::ActiveTexture(gl::TEXTURE12);`

    `gl::BindTexture(gl::TEXTURE_2D, textures[meshes[x]->current_texture]);`

Answer (score 1):

Since I could not explain why this statement: ***"I have tried re-binding the texture unit to the sampler again after the parameter change but I'm pretty sure this isn't required."*** makes no sense in comments, consider the following C pseudo-code.

```
/* Thin state wrapper */
struct SamplerObject {
  SamplerState sampler_state;
};

/* Subsumes SamplerObject */
struct TextureObject {
  ImageData*   image_data;
  ...
  SamplerState sampler_state;
};

/* Binding point: GL4.x gives you at least 80 of these (16 per-shader stage) */
struct TextureImageUnit {
  TextureObject* bound_texture; /* Default = NULL */
  SamplerObject* bound_sampler; /* Default = NULL */
} TextureUnits [16 * 5];


vec4 texture2D ( GLuint n,
                 vec2   tex_coords )
{
  /* By default, sampler state is sourced from the bound texture object */
  SamplerState* sampler_state = &TextureUnits [n]->bound_texture->sampler_state;

  /* If there is a sampler object bound to texture unit N, use its state instead
       of the sampler state built-in to the bound texture object. */
  if (TextureUnits [n]->bound_sampler != NULL)
    sampler_state = &TextureUnits [n]->bound_sampler->sampler_state;

  ...
}
```

I believe the source of confusion is coming from the fact that in GLSL the uniforms used to identify which texture image unit to sample from (and how) are called `sampler[...]`. Hopefully this clears up some of the confusion so we are all on the same page.

Comment: Then there is no way you could ever bind a texture unit to a sampler. The only world in which this would make any sense is if you were confusing GLSL samplers with sampler objects.

Comment: I don't understand your argument, a sampler object would make no use whatsoever unless you bound it to a texture unit.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: That is my point exactly, you do not bind texture units to sampler objects. You bind sampler objects to texture units. I thought the pseudo-code made that pretty clear :-\

Comment: I already clarified that in a comment above:

"I think I mean to say that I bound the sampler to the texture unit, though"

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Sorry, I did not know that was what you meant, because you said "to the texture" and not "to the texture unit". ***"Texture"*** by itself usually implies texture object.

Comment: I understand the confusion; my apologies. But do you have any idea why the texture filtering is not changing based on the parameter set on the sampler object?

Comment: Are you by chance trying to switch to a texture filter that uses mip-mapping from one that does not? Sampler objects complicate the definition of a *"mipmap complete"* texture; normally when you set a mipmap filter and the texture does not have mipmaps the driver knows this before you get around to trying to sample the texture. But when texture data and filter state are managed separately it does not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43681/discussion-between-coffeeandcode-and-andon-m-coleman)